# How to use multiple timers in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm writing a JMeter test plan and facing a problem.
Consider having the following structure:

```
- Thread group  
    - Uniform Random Timer (in order to make a global timer for all tests)  
    - Transaction Controller 1  
        - Action 1  
        - Action 2  
        - Transaction Controller 2 (in this controller, I don't want to have timer between each action)  
            - Constant Timer (set timer to 0)  
            - Action 3  
            - Action 4
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work : the "Transaction Controller 2" still got a random timer and my constant timer had no effect

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that with your structure the Uniform Random Timer will execute after every action. In your case, Action 3 and Action 4 will each execute both the Uniform Random Timer AND the Constant Timer.

My approach for this would be to move the Uniform Random Timer into Transaction Controller 1, and have a different timer in Transaction Controller 2

[image: Simple Test Plan Example]

If you are going to have a universal timer, then as far as I know it will be executed on every action in the test plan, and you can not disable it for individual actions. I think it is better to have individual timers for each transaction. If you want the wait time to be the same for all (or most) of the timers, you can always set up a User Definied Variable so you only have to change the time in once place:

[image: User Defined Variables]

[image: Global Constant Timer]

Comment: The problem is that I have something more complicated than this.  
In fact, there are a lot of controllers and I just want to use the constant timer in one controller, other controllers must use the global timer.  

Like this : http://s28.postimg.org/5s53tdwyl/jmeter.png

Comment: I am not aware of any way to make a timer declared at the root level to be ignored in one particular instance - perhaps someone else will be able to suggest a way. If not then the workaround will have to be having a timer for every controller, with the time controlled by a User Defined Variable

Comment: Your workaround is ok if the test plan is simple. If you have several levels of controllers, it becomes difficult.